# I want to design a web page which is in html and css

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUvfc.jpg)

[I want to design a web page which is in html and css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCCeN.jpg)

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Well what have you tried for code???

Comment: Do you know html and css? Do you have an idea what the website will be about? Are you aware that both your links point to the same picture? And, what is the question? I don't see a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your problem, I have two suggestions for you:

1. If you have no clue on how to get started, I recommend [this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-html-css) tutsplus full course in HTML and CSS. It will teach you how to get this project done.
2. If you *already* know the basics of web programming, try being more specific with your question and not throwing in this site your homework, because nobody will make it for you.